# How to make a page accessible only after log in

Tags: php

here is my login page:login.php

```
<?php
require_once('connectvars.php');
//start the session
session_start();

//clear the error message
$error_msg="";
//If the user isn't logged in ,log them in

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //connect to database
        $dbc=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

        $user_username=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['username']));
        $user_password=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['password']));

        if(!empty($user_username)&&!empty($user_password))
        { $query="select user_id,username from gyan_userdata where username='$user_username'and password=SHA('$user_password')";                                                          

           $data=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($data)==1)
            {
                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
                $_SESSION['user_id']=$_row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['username']=$_row['username'];
                setcookie('user_id',$_row['user_id'],time()+(60*60*24*30));
                setcookie('username',$_row['username'],time()+(60*60*24*30));
                $home_url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/index2.php';
                header('Location:'.$home_url);
            }
            else
            {
                $error_msg ='<p>Your username or password combination is incorrect</p>';
            }
       }
       else
       {
           $error_msg= 'You must enter a username and password to log in';
       }
    }

 }
 $page_title='Log In';
 require_once('header.php');
 if(empty($_session['user_id']))
 {
     echo '<p class="error">'.$error_msg.'</p>';

?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br/>
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Log in" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php
 }
  else {
    // Confirm the successful log-in
    echo '<p class="login">You are logged in as ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '.</p>';
  }
?>
```

I want to make my index.php accessible only after login
I have added this code to my index.php page

here is my index page:index.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
      echo '<p>Please Login to continue <a href="login.php">Log In</a></p>';
      exit();
    }

   ?>



  <html>

 <head>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_style.css" />
</head>
<script src="dropdown.js">

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

but even after logging in I'm again asked to log in.

Comment: `$_session` that's a superglobal. It must be in uppercase.

Comment: Please notice that `$_SESSION`, as any variable in PHP is case-sensitive and as a super global variable it should be upper-case. I noticed that you're using also `$_sessions`

Comment: You're also using `$_row` but fetching the array as `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($data);` so that will fail. You need to **debug** your code. `'$user_username'and` another possible factor. Voted to close.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: well I'm new to php but I could figure out that changing the case of $_session to $_SESSION has not solved my problem.So please help if you could find any solution

Comment: You have many other errors as outlined in comments above, and have shown you how to debug your code. Do that then post the errors you are getting and add them under your question.

Comment: Thanks for it.I have got the solution.Actually I was using $row as $_row.Just a stupid mistake.

Comment: Ahhhh lovely. Glad to hear it was resolved in comments ;-) and you're welcome.

Comment: @prak I've decidde to post an answer below where you can accept it to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you're not setting $_SESSION['user_id'] properly

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
$_SESSION['user_id']=$_row['user_id'];
```

Should be

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
$_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
```

Note that $_row became $row

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `$_session` that's a superglobal. It must be in uppercase.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Then, you're using `$_row` but fetching the array using `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($data);`
*so that will fail.*

Use `$_row=mysqli_fetch_array($data);` if you want to keep what you've already coded.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

and `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()` which would have caught the syntax error.

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.